# Error ADB0020: Mono.AndroidTools.IncompatibleCpuAbiExceptiopn: The package does not support the CPU architecture of this device

Tags: .net, maui

I have installed Windows 10 20H2 version in my system. And Visual Studio Professional 2019 preview. I followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation) for MAUI setup.

I have installed .Net MAUI preview 5. And ensured maui-check. All looks great.

I able to create new project in MAUI and it builds succesfully. But when try to deploy in device, it shows below error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0020: Mono.AndroidTools.IncompatibleCpuAbiExceptiopn: The package does not support the CPU architecture of this device.
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 342
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:line 803
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 206
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 223
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<InstallPackage>d__101.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line 338
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<InstallPackage>d__101.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line 355
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<RunTaskAsync>d__96.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line 212        

0
```

I try to resolve these problem, but no luck.

Device : Samsung SM-A605G (Android 10 - API 29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your question, eventually found the answer here ...

https://vladislavantonyuk.azurewebsites.net/articles/The-first-project-with-.NET-MAUI

Comment: Here I added this on .csproj PropertyGroup:
`<RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to add RuntimeIdentifiers as pointed out by @tony

In my .csproj file i added the line with RuntimeIdentifiers as in the following snippet

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-ios;net6.0-android;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Release mode, yet the project was successfully deployed in Debug mode. Finally managed to fix the problem as follows.

Set the build configuration as Release, and then right click on project -> Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced (on the bottom of the page)

Under the Supported architectures make sure that the options of `x86`, `x86_64` and `arm64-v8a` are selected.